# Makefile if statement set MFLAGS

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying to detect what user set in MFLAGS (what kind of var type) and add proper others options (printf format):

```
CC:=gcc
CFLAGS:=-g3 -Wall -pedantic -std=c99
LDFLAGS:=
MFLAGS:=-Dcost_type="int"  < default MFLAGS
SOURCES:=...
OBJECTS:=$(SOURCES:.c=.o)
EXECUTABLE:=...

ifneq (,$(findstring "-Dcost_type=\"int\"",$(MFLAGS)))
        MFLAGS:="$(MFLAGS) -Dcost_fmt=\"%d\""
endif
ifneq (,$(findstring "double",$(MFLAGS)))
        MFLAGS:="$(MFLAGS) -Dcost_fmt=\"%f\""
endif
...
```

But that example isn't reacting on any of that inputs:

```
make MFLAGS:="-Dcost_type=\"int\""
make MFLAGS:="-Dcost_type=\"double\""
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple issues here,

1. You will need to use 'override' to change the variables from commandline
2. Do not quote the string passed to findstring

rewrite to something like this,

```
ifneq (,$(findstring -Dcost_type="int",$(MFLAGS)))
override MFLAGS += " -Dcost_fmt=\"%d\""
endif
ifneq (,$(findstring double,$(MFLAGS)))
override MFLAGS += " -Dcost_fmt=\"%f\""
endif
```

Comment: Could you look at my problems posted below?

Comment: have you looked at my response below, is this already resolved ?

Answer (score 0):

I have to ask again for some help. I wrote that makefile, it works for "int", but not for "short" (why?). And what about space (eg. long long), because it use "long" case not "long long" when I do: make MFLAGS=-Dcost_type="\"long long\""

```
ifneq (,$(findstring short,$(MFLAGS)))
        override MLAGS+=-Dcost_fmt=\"%hd\" -Dcost_max=SHRT_MAX
endif
ifneq (,$(findstring unsigned short,$(MFLAGS)))
        override MFLAGS+=-Dcost_fmt=\"%hd\" -Dcost_max=USHRT_MAX
endif
ifneq (,$(findstring int,$(MFLAGS)))
        override MFLAGS+=-Dcost_fmt=\"%d\" -Dcost_max=INT_MAX
endif
ifneq (,$(findstring unsigned int,$(MFLAGS)))
        override MFLAGS+=-Dcost_fmt=\"%d\" -Dcost_max=UINT_MAX
endif
ifneq (,$(findstring long,$(MFLAGS)))
        override MFLAGS+=-Dcost_fmt=\"%ld\" -Dcost_max=LONG_MAX
endif
ifneq (,$(findstring unsigned long,$(MFLAGS)))
        override MFLAGS+=-Dcost_fmt=\"%ld\" -Dcost_max=ULONG_MAX
endif
ifneq (,$(findstring long long,$(MFLAGS)))
        override MFLAGS+=-Dcost_fmt=\"%lld\" -Dcost_max=LLONG_MAX
endif
ifneq (,$(findstring unsigned long long,$(MFLAGS)))
        override MFLAGS+=-Dcost_fmt=\"%lld\" -Dcost_max=ULLONG_MAX
endif
ifneq (,$(findstring float,$(MFLAGS)))
        override MFLAGS+=-Dcost_fmt=\"%f\" -Dcost_max=FLT_MAX
endif
ifneq (,$(findstring double,$(MFLAGS)))
        override MFLAGS+=-Dcost_fmt=\"%f\" -Dcost_max=DBL_MAX
endif
ifneq (,$(findstring long double,$(MFLAGS)))
        override MFLAGS+=-Dcost_fmt=\"%Lf\" -Dcost_max=LDBL_MAX
endif
```

Comment: You have a typo here `override MLAGS+=-Dcost_fmt=\"%hd\" -Dcost_max=SHRT_MAX`. fix `MLAGS` to `MFLAGS`. Now this should work for `short`. `long` will match `long long` as well. you can either nest the if conditions or do an exact match. `ifneq (,$(findstring long,$(MFLAGS)))
   ifneq (,$(findstring long long,$(MFLAGS)))
       override MFLAGS+=-Dcost_fmt=\"%lld\" -Dcost_max=LLONG_MAX
   else
       override MFLAGS+=-Dcost_fmt=\"%ld\" -Dcost_max=LONG_MAX
   endif
endif` OR `ifeq (long long,$(findstring long long,$(MFLAGS)))
override MFLAGS="EXACTMATCH"
endif
`